# UIWebView works well in Simulator but not in iPad device

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, simulator

I have a native app which run well in both simulator and ipad device.

But there is a `UIWebView` to load static HTML files, most HTML page run well, but only one web page has the issue : simulator can run well , but can not show completely on device.

How many possible causes for this sort of issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more info

maybe using metadata to adjust to the device could work

> meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
>   maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" /

on the static page could help